# LaTeX unwanted itemize indentation on first element

Tags: latex

In my document whenever I use `itemize`, the first element has an unwanted indentation. In each chapter I use `\ident`, could this be causing a problem?
How to I fix the unwanted indentation? 
I want to keep the standard itemize indentation and just adjust the first item.
The document is being edited on Overleaf.

This is what is looks like:

[image: This is what is looks like:]

My goal

[image: My goal]

This is in an example code which replicates the issue for me:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={Your Title},
 pdfauthor={Your Name},
 pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig} 
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
\PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%-----------HEADER AND FOOTER DEFINITION-----------%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headheight}{0.7in}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\rhead{% left
\raisebox{0.25in}{\textcolor{gray}{\large Namen}}
}
\lhead{ % right
  % \transparent{0.5}\includegraphics[height=0.6in]{Logo_novo_FEUPbranco.jpg}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}




%\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-5pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\large\slshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{45pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

% ------------------ TITLE PAGE -------------------

\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\center % Center everything on the page






%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textsc{\Large xxxxt }\\[1.5cm] 


\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \bfseries \textbf{ title:} Here\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[1cm]
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------


%\begin{minipage}[b][][b]{\linewidth}

\end{titlepage}

% ------------------------------- body --------------------

%%%%%%%%--------- TABLE OF CONTENT ----------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
\tableofcontents

%%%%%%%%%%-------- ABSTRACT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
  \paragraph{}
  \par  The fu 

\end{abstract}

%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\section{Introduction} \label{introduction}



\indent 
\par In

\par This report is divided in xx fs:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Chapter 2:
    \item Chapter 3:
    \item Chapter 4:
    \item Chapter 5:
\end{itemize}  

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? This is not default behaviour.

Comment: This only happens when I write inside a \section, if I do it inside a \subsection it doens't happen. I've tried defining an indent for the whole itemize, but it  solve the issue.

Comment: @samcarter I've added all the code I am using in the section which is causing my issue. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: Please make a compilable MWE, not just a code fragment. If you need help to create a MWE, follow the link in my first comment.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\indent 
\par Text starts
\par more text
\begin{itemize}
    \item Chapter 2:
    \item Chapter 3:
    \item Chapter 4:
    \item Chapter 5:
\end{itemize}


\end{document}` works just fine, we really need some code that replicates the problem

Comment: I've managed to narrow down my code to a simplified version which replicates the problem (at least on Overleaf it does).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is utterly unrelated to the itemization, you should not even know how the itemisation looks like. You must not have `\paragraph{}` within the `abstract` environment. This will cause an error:

[image]

## Never ever ignore errors!

And don't even look at what might or might not be a valid pdf file if there are still errors!

After an error tex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, it does not attempt to produce reasonable output.

---

Other problems:

- `hyperref` should be loaded as one of the last packages
- `\center` only works by accident, better use `\centering`
- TeX aims to separate the layout and the content. The fact that you have to mess with formatting instructions inside your text, e.g. \indent\par`should tell you that there is something fundamentally wrong. For example if the first paragraph of a section should be indented, use the`indentfirst` package.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig} 
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
\PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={Your Title},
 pdfauthor={Your Name},
 pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false}

%-----------HEADER AND FOOTER DEFINITION-----------%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headheight}{0.7in}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\rhead{% left
\raisebox{0.25in}{\textcolor{gray}{\large Namen}}
}
\lhead{ % right
  % \transparent{0.5}\includegraphics[height=0.6in]{Logo_novo_FEUPbranco.jpg}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}




%\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-5pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\large\slshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{45pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

% ------------------ TITLE PAGE -------------------

\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\centering % Center everything on the page






%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textsc{\Large xxxxt }\\[1.5cm] 


\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \bfseries \textbf{ title:} Here\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[1cm]
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------


%\begin{minipage}[b][][b]{\linewidth}

\end{titlepage}

% ------------------------------- body --------------------

%%%%%%%%--------- TABLE OF CONTENT ----------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
\tableofcontents

%%%%%%%%%%-------- ABSTRACT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
%  \paragraph{}
    The fu 
\end{abstract}

%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\section{Introduction} \label{introduction}

In

This report is divided in xx fs:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Chapter 2:
    \item Chapter 3:
    \item Chapter 4:
    \item Chapter 5:
\end{itemize}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: worked for me in the similar case, where the first item had no identation instead